# animated bubble effect in amchart 5 on map pointers

Tags: javascript, pointers, amcharts5

I want this type of animation on my amchart map chart while data is getting changed

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-with-animated-bubbles/

While I'm trying to put this it is not working can anyone tell me what should i update to achieve this?

here is my code https://codepen.io/anoopkumarseth/pen/RwdVyoL?editors=1010

I already tried to apply this code but not working

```
pointSeries.set("heatRules", [
 {
    target: circleTemplate,
    dataField: "value",
    min: 10,
    max: 50,
    minValue: 0,
    maxValue: 100,
    key: "radius"
 }
]);
```